# Setting view width constraint from custom UIView class not updating frames

Tags: swift, autolayout, nib

I've got a UIView in which I want to have a simple loader view by using a percentage to determine the width.

I've got the percentage code completed and I know it's working.

However I'm having trouble setting the view's width constraint. I find the width by getting the frame width and multiplying it by the percentage. I know it's getting the right width. But I can't seem to set the constraint from this function.

My code goes like this in my UIView subclass:

```
func initSubviews() {
    // in here i do some other stuff and have an asyncronous call to an api
    // so then I've got this code calling the next function
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.setCompletionWidth(nextTimer: nextTimer!, oldDate: oldDate!)
    }
}

func setCompletionWidth(nextTimer: Date, oldDate: Date) {
   let date = Date()

   // calculatePercent returns something like 0.49
   let percent = calculatePercent(middleDate: date, endDate: nextTimer, originalDate: oldDate)

   //this is returning a correct value
   let width = (self.frame.width)*percent

// completionView is the view I'm trying to change the width of
   self.completionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
   self.layoutSubviews()
}
```

What's happening is that the completionView isn't getting the right width.
I've also tried in the setCompletionWidth function

```
self.completionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
containerView.layoutSubviews()
```

and

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    self.completionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
    self.containerView.layoutSubviews()
    //also tried self.layoutSubviews here
}
```

and

```
self.layoutIfNeeded()
self.completionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I'm expecting the width of the completionView to be something like 150, but instead it's 350, which is the original width it had.

I think what's happening is the view isn't updating after me setting the constraint to a different value. However, I can't for the life of me get it to update. I'd love some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `.isActive = true`

```
self.completionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
```

Also to change the width you need to create a width var like

```
var widthCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

---

```
widthCon =  self.completionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
widthCon.isActive = true
```

Then change the constant with

```
widthCon.constant = /// some value 
self.superview!.layoutIfNeeded()
```